# Java - Android GPS crash when checking latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, gps, openstreetmap

Good Morning, I have trouble with my android app, everything works perfectly until for this moment, when I want to check when user is at current latitude and longitude. Android Studio does not show any errors with it, however when this part of code is not commented it causes app crash.

```
    if (latitude.equals("52,68068") && logitude.equals("19,04763"))
    {
        String Url = "http://www.google.com";
        if (!Url.startsWith("http://") && !Url.startsWith("https://"))
        {
            Url= "http://" + Url;
        }
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Url)));
    }


        //  Database credentials
        String USER = "sa";
        String PASS = "admin";
```

That's the part I use for getting latitude and longitude

```
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //saving the position to variable
            latitude = location.getLatitude() + "";
            logitude = location.getLongitude() + "";
            //executing connectionDB2 to update Database position
            new ConnectionDB2().execute();
        }
```

Comment: what is the crash message you get over ADB?

Comment: Can you post the Exception and show which line is causing it ? And showing how are you getting longitude and latitude would help too.